# How do I combine two vectors of different length in R

Tags: r

I have a set of measurements done regularly, but some are missing:

```
      measurement_date value
1  2011-01-17 13:00:00     5
2  2011-01-17 13:04:00     5
3  2011-01-17 13:08:00     7
4  2011-01-17 13:12:00     8
5  2011-01-17 13:16:00     4
6  2011-01-17 13:24:00     6
7  2011-01-17 13:28:00     5
8  2011-01-17 13:32:00     6
9  2011-01-17 13:36:00     9
10 2011-01-17 13:40:00     8
11 2011-01-17 13:44:00     6
12 2011-01-17 13:48:00     6
13 2011-01-17 13:52:00     4
14 2011-01-17 13:56:00     6
```

I have a function that's going to process the values and can handle missing values, but the row has to be there so I'm generating an array that has a row for every minute like this:

```
times <- timeSequence(from=.., length=60, by="min")
```

Now I have a row for each minute of the hour but I need to merge the data. I tried something like this but couldn't quite get it right:

```
lapply(times, function(time) {
    n <- as.numeric(time)
    v <- Position(function(candidate) {
        y <- as.numeric(candiated)
        n == y
    }

    .. insert the value into the row here ..
}
```

but I'm only getting errors and warnings. Am I going around the problem the right way? I really want a "complete" array with values per minute as there will be many different functions that will be run of the readings and it just makes it easier to implement them if they can assume that it's all there.

Comment: Try to provide at least a reproducible example as Gavin showed you. Plus, I have the feeling you're making things overly complex. I can't think of a case where you have to add NA's for a function to work.

Comment: See FAQ #13 in the zoo FAQ: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-faq.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DF <- data.frame(measurement_date = seq(as.POSIXct("2011-01-17 13:00:00"),
                                        as.POSIXct("2011-01-17 13:56:00"),
                                        by = "mins")[seq(1, 57, by = 4)][-6],
                 value = c(5,5,7,8,4,6,5,6,9,8,6,6,4,6))
full <- data.frame(measurement_date = seq(as.POSIXct("2011-01-17 13:00:00"),
                                          by = "mins", length = 60),
                   value = rep(NA, 60))
```

Two approaches can be used, the first via `merge`:

```
> v1 <- merge(full, DF, by.x = 1, by.y = 1, all = TRUE)[, c(1,3)]
> names(v1)[2] <- "value" ## I only reset this to pass all.equal later
> head(v1)
     measurement_date value
1 2011-01-17 13:00:00     5
2 2011-01-17 13:01:00    NA
3 2011-01-17 13:02:00    NA
4 2011-01-17 13:03:00    NA
5 2011-01-17 13:04:00     5
6 2011-01-17 13:05:00    NA
```

The second is via an indicator variable derived using `%in%`:

```
> want <- full$measurement_date %in% DF$measurement_date
> full[want, "value"] <- DF[, "value"]
> head(full)
     measurement_date value
1 2011-01-17 13:00:00     5
2 2011-01-17 13:01:00    NA
3 2011-01-17 13:02:00    NA
4 2011-01-17 13:03:00    NA
5 2011-01-17 13:04:00     5
6 2011-01-17 13:05:00    NA
> all.equal(v1, full)
[1] TRUE
```

The merge version is **strongly** preferred, but needs a little work. The `%in%` solution only works here because the data are in time order in both `DF` and `full`, hence my earlier "preferred". It is easy to get/ensure the two objects in time order however, so both approaches require a little finesse-ing to work. We can modify the `%in%` approach to get both variables in order (starting afresh with `full`):

```
full2 <- data.frame(measurement_date = seq(as.POSIXct("2011-01-17 13:00:00"),
                                           by = "mins", length = 60),
                    value = rep(NA, 60))
full2 <- full2[order(full2[,1]), ] ## get full2 in order
DF2 <- DF[order(DF[,1]), ]         ## get DF in order
want <- full$measurement_date %in% DF$measurement_date
full2[want, "value"] <- DF2[, "value"]

>     all.equal(full, full2)
[1] TRUE
>     all.equal(full2, v1)
[1] TRUE
>
```

Comment: Indeed... (+1) "The Joris-Gavin Mutual Appreciation Society"

Comment: The second solution depends on row order to be correct. Slightly better version would be `want <- match(DF$measurement_date, full$measurement_date)`. But there are so many pitfalls (duplicate ids, etc) that the merge solution is strongly preferred.

Comment: @Eduardo Thanks - given that the time ordering is the same there is no harm in using `%in%` here, but your point is well made and I have emphasised that merge is strongly preferred.

Comment: Something appears to have unsynchronised itself in my answer between emacs and pasting the code into the answer. The `merge` was missing some finesse-ing to handle rows that matched in *both* objects and to correct the `names(full)[2])`. Without this, the code I had originally returned 74 rows and was clearly not `all.equal(v1, full)`. In addition, I've added something to address the time ordering issue raised in the comments.

Comment: I just figured that 
`seq(as.POSIXct("2011-01-17 13:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2011-01-17 13:56:00"), by = "mins")[seq(1, 57, by = 4)]`
can be written more easily as 
`seq(as.POSIXct("2011-01-17 13:00:00"),length=60 / 4, by = "4 mins")`

Comment: @trygis nice, I didn't realise you could do that sort of thing. I've learned a second new thing today (the first was what weird things palaeoceanographers do to their data and get away with!)

Answer (score 6):

In your function, as.numeric(candiated) should be as.numeric(candidate). There's also a bracket missing. I have no clue what exactly you're trying to achieve in your function, but it looks horrendously complex to me.

Try

```
merge(Data,times,by.x=1,by.y=1,all.y=T)
```

This should give you something to work with.